# Optimization of algorithm that convert 8-bit number to char

Tags: c#, .net, char

I need to convert a 8-bit number such as `00001110` to char. The problem is easy so I wrote the code and everything is working fine, but now I need to optimize for speed as much as possible.

In test class :

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] testTab = new int[8];
        Normal n = new Normal();
        long time;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                testTab[j] = r.Next(2);
            }
            n.SetTable(testTab);
            n.Decode();
        }
        watch.Stop();
        time = watch.ElapsedTicks;
        Console.WriteLine(time);
        time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine(time);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
```

and class with algorithm :

```
class Normal
{
    private int[] _tab = new int[8];

    public void SetTable(int[] tab)
    {
        _tab = tab;
    }
    public void Decode()
    {
        char a = ((char)( _tab[0]*1 + _tab[1]*2 + _tab[2]*4 + _tab[3]*8 + _tab[4]*16 + _tab[5]*32 +
                          _tab[6]*64 + _tab[7]*124));
    }
}
```

In the output for 9000 times I get time 2ms it is not a long time  ( for 9000 ) time, but I have good proc in my PC.

The final code will be running in smartphone so there is no powerful CPU. In my algorithm I use random data, in final version I will load data by Camera (so it will be longer ) and try to repeat this operation 10 times in one second so that is why I need best time in even smallest operations.

Is there a faster way to convert byte to char than this?

`char a = ((char)( _tab[0]*1 + _tab[1]*2 + _tab[2]*4 + _tab[3]*8 + _tab[4]*16 + _tab[5]*32 + _tab[6]*64 + _tab[7]*128));`

Comment: Why do you use an `int[]` for Bits? These fit in an `int`! Read about Bit Manipulation: &, |, ^

Comment: why not `Char result = (Char) (random.Next(256));`?

Comment: I use int because i wrote for test so i don't mind of a memory just need time int is same speed as byte. In final i will make it as small as possible but now is only test

Comment: @Aht BTW: `64*2=>128` not 124

Comment: @DmitryBychenko in my app i will have array of bits ( 8 bits ) so i work oin bits

Comment: @EZI Damm ... Yea sorry :)

Comment: Where does the real data come from? Do you really need to have binary strings?

Comment: Why `char`? You shouldn't really *ever* cast to (or from) `char` in .NET. If you need a single byte, use `byte`. If you really need a `char`, use `Encoding` with the appropriate encoding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Data will come from phone camera i will try to read QR code which is save in 8 bits sections

Comment: It makes no sense at all to convert an 8 bit value to 16 bit UTF-16 character. I don't believe that you really understand the problem yet. Let us help you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes u have right. i will need to ignore last bit and convert it to ascii Sorry. And sorry for my bad answer time i have bad internet

Comment: No. Convert it to a byte. Put it into a byte array. And use Encoding.GetString to decode to text. Anyway, my answer attempts to explain why perf of this conversion is not a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Your conversion code is already efficient, and is not your bottleneck.

---

Your benchmarking is flawed. You are not just timing the conversion of binary stored in `int[]` to integer value. You are also timing the generation of your random data. I expect that the majority of the time is spent generating the random data.

Re-write your benchmarking program to operate on data prepared before you start timing. Make sure that the duration of the test is at least 5 or 10 seconds so that you can generate meaningful answers. If you only run for two milliseconds then the granularity of your timer affects the quality of your results.

Bear in mind that in your real application you will be taking a picture on a camera of a QR code and decoding that. The cost of that is many orders of magnitude greater than the cost of converting the 8 bit int arrays.

Your code to do that conversion is already efficient. Do not seek to optimize it further. Not only is there no need to optimize it, there is little hope for significant gains. For the sake of clarity and conciseness you may well opt to use one of the .net library methods that perform such a conversion, but performance of this part of your program is not an issue.

As an aside, it looks like you need to be converting the 8 bit value to byte, adding these values to a byte array, and then feeding to `Encoding.GetString` to obtain your text. A cast to UTF-16 `char` as per your code is not correct.

Comment: I know that this benchmarking is baad. I wrote this. I known that will must decoding QR, make pic, make some photo work and this will take longer time than convert bits to char but when i thinning about my code i try to make it fast in every part thats why i start from smallest part. But if u say that i will no gain real time in this poeration i said ok i trust u :) i think i will back when i will convert photo ( that will must be optymalized perfect so i will need help from expert :) )

Comment: It's important that you learn to identify bottlenecks and optimise those first. Do that until performance is acceptable. It's a huge waste of time optimising code that is not a bottleneck because you won't be able to observe any improvement, and you'll likely make your code harder to read an maintain. Premature optimization usually makes your code worse.

Comment: I will remember that advice

Answer (score 1):

It worth a try this:

```
var yourString = "00100000";
char yourChar = (char) Convert.ToByte(yourString, 2); // you got ' ' (space)
```

It may or may not faster, but definitely simpler, more stable and more maintainable.

Comment: This will convert char to byte ? I need convert byte to char :D

Comment: This will convert a string representation of a 8 bit number to char, exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests with different implementations.
First was @Melnikovl answer.
Second was mine, where I replaced `+` with `|` and `*` with `<<` operator.
Third was author's original solution.

I tested with modified code and measured only conversion code.
First and second solution showed a little better performance. But `BitConverter` a little more often was better, so I think you should choose it (also because if simplicity of code)

Answer (score -1):

```
var byte[] bytes = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
char a = (char)i;
```

Don't forgot to check if byte array litte or big endian

Comment: Perhaps because there is no coverage of the issue of perf?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it worth to comment and ask author about it, but downvote? It's still answer the question. And it do it better than other one (where conversion from string)